# How do distributed algorithms for shortest path finding handle negative cycles?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, distributed-systems, routing

I am searching the web for an answer to this question, but I have only found answers for non-distributed algorithms. I am interested in this for its application to Distance Vector routing.

Comment: "Distributed computation on graphs: Shortest path algorithms" by Chandy and Misra might be useful to you, although it is old (written in 1982). You could try searching for newer articles that cite it if it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: "for its application to Distance Vector routing". Can you explain how a routing graph could have a negative cycle?

Comment: An example where a routing graph can have a negative weight is if these are weights given to represent monetary cost of sending traffic through that link.